# Extract low-res thumbnails and photo meta data from backup file?

Tags: ipad, backup, photos, geolocation

I have ~4000 photos which are missing from iCloud and I have not been able to find in any backups anywhere. The photos can still be viewed on the Photos app of an old iPad. Photos cannot be transferred off or airdopped because the full-sized images haven't been downloaded. I am hoping to somehow extract the thumbnails form the iPad if anyone has any idea?

I have been able to backup the iPad locally and can access the backup file. Is there anyway to extract the photos + the geolocation and date/time metadata from the backup or iPad? I know the photos will be very low-res but it's better than losing them all.